# What was the original relation between Luke Skywalker and his aunt and uncle?

Tags: star-wars, luke-skywalker

In the original Star Wars movie, Luke lives with Uncle Owen and Aunt Beru, who talk about how Luke is like his father.  When Luke discovers that Vader is his father in ESB, and then tells Leia, it is implied that Leia was raised by their mother who Luke never knew.

Obviously, this is not how the prequels portray this; they instead have Padme die in childbirth and Luke is sent to live with Owen and Beru.  Anakin's mother married Owen's father, technically making Owen Anakin's stepbrother and Luke's uncle.  But this is a pretty far removed method of relating them - and it certainly doesn't seem like the original plan.

What was the original relationship between Luke and his aunt and uncle?  Was Uncle Owen supposed to be his father's brother?  As Leia is a princess, it would seem to make sense that she was raised by their mother, who was a queen, and likely doesn't have a sibling living on Tatooine.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Luke was originally *unrelated* to Owen and Beru. Owen was Obi-Wan's (non-Jedi) brother.

> Ben continued his narrative. “When your father left, he didn’t know
> your mother was pregnant. Your mother and I knew he would find out
> eventually, but we wanted to keep you both as safe as possible, for as
> long as possible. **So I took you to live with my brother Owen, on
> Tatooine …** and your mother took Leia to live as the daughter of
> Senator Organa, on Alderaan.”
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars: Return of the Jedi - Official Novelisation](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_VI:_Return_of_the_Jedi_(novel))</sup></sub>

Note that in earlier treatments Luke's father and Vader weren't

> the same person.

Comment: +1 for using the spoiler tag in Luke and Vader's relationship

Comment: +1 for Obi-Wan being a filthy liar

Comment: Only a liar from a certain point of view.

Comment: The book *The Secret History of Star Wars* says the idea of Owen as Obi-Wan's brother comes from the Return of the Jedi novelization, not the New Hope novelization (confirmed [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=3QPTCwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA66&pg=PA66)), and that this was a sort of a retcon to explain why hiding Luke with Vader's brother on Vader's home planet wouldn't have been a really stupid idea (the Secret History book presents a bunch of evidence that when A New Hope was written, "Annikin" and Vader weren't imagined as the same person, and Owen really was meant to be Annikin's brother)

Comment: This answer is mistaken - that quote comes from the ROTJ novelization (p66), which you can tell by the fact that it mentions Leia as Luke's sister. The idea of keeping Owen as Obi-Wan's brother was around as late as 1999: https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Owen_(Kenobi)#Behind_the_scenes

Answer (score 1):

[Luke Skywalker](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Luke_Skywalker) was related to [Owen](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Owen_Lars) and [Beru Lars](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Beru_Whitesun_Lars) because when his grandmother, [Shmi Skywalker](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Shmi_Skywalker_Lars) was sold by [Watto](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Watto) to [Cliegg Lars](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Cliegg_Lars), she was freed and then married Cliegg. Owen was Cliegg's son and therefore the step-brother of [Anakin Skywalker](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Anakin_Skywalker). This is explained in Star Wars: Attack of the Clones:

> Owen: Well... I guess I'm your step-brother. I had a feeling you might show up someday.
>
> *-Star Wars, Episode II: Attack of the Clones*

Therefore, Owen and Beru are technically Luke's **step-aunt** and **step-uncle**, but it is generally referred to as them being just his "aunt and uncle".

Does that answer your question?

Comment: The question is about the out-of-universe evolution of the character, not in-universe state of the character.